# NHibernate - How to project a subquery as a column with a QueryOver

Tags: subquery, queryover

How would one achieve the following sql with the new NHibernate 3.0 QueryOver API?

```
select name, (select customertype from types where id = customer.id)
from customer
```

This is a simple query achievable with a standard join, but used to highlight the problem.